# How to combine two GNOME panels into one

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel

I have GNOME with two panels:
- top panel with menus (launcher);
- bottom panel with taskbar.
How can I combine this two panels into one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way to combine the two panels into one is simply to add the panel widgets from one bar to the other and then to delete the empty bar.

The following panel applets make up the standard top-panel:

- Menu Bar - custom menu bar
- Indicator Complete

The following panel applets make up the standard bottom-panel:

- Show Desktop
- Window List
- Workspace Switcher

In the answer below - the magic sequence to modify the panel is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> + Right Click of the mouse.

Lets first delete the bottom panel:

[image: pic]

Next, add the panel widgets listed above for the bottom panel to the top-panel

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

Finally, move each of the widgets to your desired position - use the magic combination but make sure you right-click of the widget itself:

[image: pic]

So the final combined panel could look something like:

[image: pic]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you send/add your answer to FAQ of Ubuntu?